# WPF (VS2010/.NET4.0) Create a re-usable form layout

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, custom-controls

In a nutshell what Im trying to achieve is to have a re-usable DLL which will potentially have a wizard like form. I could then simply set the content. Ive spent quite a bit of time searching but Im still not sure whats the best way to go. Ive had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883837/how-to-create-reusable-wpf-grid-layout) article as well.

Ive got the following structure in the XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding ScreenTitleText}" />
    <Label x:Name="ContentTitle" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding ContentTitleText}"  />
    <Button x:Name="BackButton" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Content="Back"  />
    <Button x:Name="NextButton" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Content="Next"   />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding InnerContent}" x:Name="InnerControl"/>
</Grid>
```

1. Id like to know how to make it so that I could set the content on row=4 and column=2 to say for example a set of radio buttons.
2. How to have this code in a DLL so that I could re-use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this as a WPF User Control in a Class Library or a WPF User Control Library. Then, put ContentControls where you want the dynamic stuff to go. You can expose DataTemplate properties for each of those ContentControls. The ContentControls can bind their Template to a DataTemplate and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for that @Brent. Im not sure how  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" can have a ContentControl. My understanding is that ContentControl can only have one item within it and we utilise it Content property. I'd like to have various items that can be set in position Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2". Or am I missing something where you're saying I should use the Template property? Cheers.

Comment: If you place a ContentControl at Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2", it could be used as a placeholder for the various items you would like to place there. That is assuming you want to place them there one at a time. Of course, there's nothing stopping you from having that one item be a Grid or some other Panel control containing multiple items.

Comment: I mentioned the DataTemplates as an option for your UserControl to provide a way to change out the contents of the ContentControls. Just an option that could keep your UserControl dynamic.