# Setting columnDefinition and RowDefinition from style template?

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, uwp

Is it possible to add the follow code:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

into a `Style` / `Setter` template for a `Grid`? And then automatically setup the `RowDefinitions` for a `Grid` like this?

```
<Grid style="{StaticResource MyRowDefs}">
    <Button  Grid.Row="0" Content="Button1/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button  Grid.Row="2" Content="Button2/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this solve your issue: [How to create reusable WPF grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883837/how-to-create-reusable-wpf-grid-layout)

For your example, you could do something like:

```
<Window x:Class="ReUseGridTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReUseGridTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GridItemsStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource GridItemsStyle}">
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Button1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="Test"/>
        <Button  Grid.Row="2" Content="Button2"/>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the `RowDefinitions` property in a `Style` because it's not a dependency property but you can create a custom `Grid` type and use this one:

```
public class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    public CustomGrid()
    {
        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };
        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:CustomGrid>
    <Button  Grid.Row="0" Content="Button1/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button  Grid.Row="2" Content="Button2/>
</local:CustomGrid>
```