# WPF style for Grid with defined columns and rows?

Tags: wpf, templates, styles

In my application I have a lot of grids like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

They have 4 columns and 3 rows and column widths are set to some value.

**Can I create style or some other kind of template to simplify my window that uses 20 grids like this?**

I know, that I can create styles for column definitions one by one to avoid `Width="10"` everywhere, but is it possible to do something like this?

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource GridWith4ColumnsAnd3Rows}">
    <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in this entry? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883837/how-to-create-reusable-wpf-grid-layout

Comment: I just did. Thanks! I just flagged my question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice answer is here:

[How to create reusable WPF grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883837/how-to-create-reusable-wpf-grid-layout)

I have used `<ItemsPanel>` control with `Grid` inside.

**Style (in my App.xaml):**

```
<Style x:Key="SchedulerFieldGridStyle1" TargetType="ItemsControl" >
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid Background="LightSteelBlue" Margin="4">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Part of MainWindow.xaml **before**:

```
<Grid Background="LightSteelBlue" Margin="4">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Content="Day of week"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="From"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="To"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Part of MainWindow.xaml **after:**

```
<ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource SchedulerFieldGridStyle1}">
    <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Content="Day of week"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="From"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="To"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Don't know why anyone downvoted this, this seems like a really neat solution to me

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the `RowDefinitions` or `ColumnDefinitions` properties in a `Style` because they are not dependency properties.

But you could create a custom class that inherits from `Grid` and adds the `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinition` in the constructor:

```
public class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    public CustomGrid()
    {
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10) });
        //...
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:CustomGrid>...</local:CustomGrid>
```

Alternatively, you could define an [attached behaviour](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) that creates the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions`.